# How does reduced relay chain block time affect parachain blocks?

Tags: parachain

Regarding the [async backing](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/open-discussion-thread-fall-2022-roadmap-roundup/542), I'm struggling to understand how the reduced relay chain block time (of 6 seconds) affect parachain block times?

We have vesting schedules based on the parachain block numbers (block time of 12 seconds). Will they be affected at all?

Comment: one correction: Polkadot/Kusama relay chain block time is (and has been) [6 seconds](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/d57049f1e4e5b00309cdd0297235a8de821f601d/runtime/polkadot/constants/src/lib.rs#L44).

Comment: @Iker Thanks for pointing it out. I completely misunderstood this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do think it will depend very much on how your schedule is designed. There is an existing discussion with possible solutions found on the forum thread on the [Polkadot Roadmap](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/open-discussion-thread-fall-2022-roadmap-roundup/542/12). Found here:
https://forum.polkadot.network/t/open-discussion-thread-fall-2022-roadmap-roundup/542/12